# no sound after suspend/resume

Tags: 12.04, sound, suspend

I have no audio on lubuntu 12.04 after resuming from suspend. I tried `sudo alsa force-reload` to no avail. Sound works after reboot. Please help.

Comment: Does `sudo alsa force-reload` output anything? It might help to get some more information about your system, like your sound card: `lspci | grep -i audio`

Comment: It's really sad that it's almost 3 years later and this is still an issue (i3-5010u brix on Ubuntu 15.04).  I usually shut down, and I'm on an SSD so a full reboot is about 10-15 seconds, but having to re-open what I happened to have open isn't fun.  This is on my HTPC, if it were my desktop it would really piss me off.

Comment: Upvoted because **`sudo alsa force-reload`** solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For some systems it is necessary to kill the pulseaudio process and prevent it from re-loading before restarting ALSA. If the following procedure works, it can be [automated](https://askubuntu.com/a/116043/2906).

1. Set up Pulseaudio so it does not respawn automatically:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.pulse
   echo "autospawn = no" >> ~/.pulse/client.conf
   ```
2. Suspend your computer and wake him up
3. Restart ALSA:

   ```
   sudo alsa force-reload
   ```
4. Start pulseaudio:

   ```
   pulseaudio --start
   ```

To revert the changes, delete the file *~/.pulse/client.conf*

Answer (score 3):

After consulting some posts, what I've done to get mine to work again:

1. Set pulseaudio not to respawn by creating config file at home
   directory:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.pulse
   echo "autospawn = no" >> ~/.pulse/client.conf
   ```
2. Create a file (50alsa) to automate after system suspend.

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/50alsa
   ```
3. Add the following to the file. Notice 'pulseaudio --kill' added.

   ```
   case "$1" in
           hibernate|suspend)
                   # Stopping is not required
                   ;;
           thaw|resume)
                   pulseaudio --kill                
                   /sbin/alsa force-reload
                   pulseaudio --start
                   ;; 
           *) exit $NA
                   ;;
   esac
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to change `tty` screens then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to desktop.

This sometimes brings back sound but failing that, change screen resolution and change it back for a different fix. This works for HDMI audio as well.

Comment: This worked for me, while I got disappointed after applying other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/809849/34298), but that didn't help.

To solve this without restart or another suspend, I solved it with simply

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```