# HDMI Audio Device Missing After Resume From Sleep

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio, hdmi

I recently switched from DisplayPort to HDMI for connecting my computer to my display. Generally, the audio works fine via the built-in speakers in the monitor via HDMI but after the computer goes to sleep it no longer works. I have checked the Sound settings and there are no output devices listed. Any ideas?

This occurs on Ubuntu 18.10 and I upgraded to 19.04 today and the issue persists.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
```

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.0.0-13-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-020) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)) #14-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 14:59:14 UTC 2019
```

Before: [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgyRQ.png)

After: [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Ci4.png)

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu: Which version of Ubuntu and Kernel are you using? (run `lsb_release -a` and `cat /proc/version` in the console, then update your question)

Comment: Sorry, details added.

Comment: This sounds like a dupe of [question 762816](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762816/ubuntu-16-04-changes-sound-device-after-suspend-how-to-fix) or [question 777515](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777515/no-hdmi-audio-after-suspend).

Comment: What is the output of `pactl list short sinks` and `pactl info`? Try to run `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio` and report whether restarting pulseaudio that way fixes your problem